# How observes nested properties in Ember.Array

Tags: arrays, ember.js, observable

Suppose I have a model `Stock` that has several `StockPartition` (its a property called `partitions`, its an Array).

The `Stock` model has a property `usedAmount` that should change when any of all `partition.amount` changes, and, of course, be updated when a partition is added/removed.

Example :

```
stock.get('usedAmount') -> 0
stock.get('partitions') -> [Class, Class, Class]
stock.get('partitions')[0].set('amount', 12)
stock.get('usedAmount') -> I want here to return 12
stock.get('partitions')[1].set('amount', 12)
stock.get('usedAmount') -> I want here 24
```

How could `Stock` observes each `partitions.amount`?
I can write a function `addPartition` that looks like this :

```
addPartition: function(partition) {
  partition.addObserver('amount', function() {
    this.get('owner').notifyPropertyChange('usedAmount');
  });
}
```

But I hope there is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make usage of the powerful computed properties. Also you can make usage of the helpful methods available on  `Ember.Enumerable`'s, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/BxyY4/:

```js
App.partitionsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [],

    addPartition: function(amount) {
        this.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
            amount: amount
        }));
    },

    usedAmount: function() {
        // reduce by adding all 'amount' values, start with initial value 0
        return this.reduce(function(previousValue, item) {
            return previousValue + item.get('amount');
        }, 0);
    }.property('@each.amount')
});
```

The `reduce` is documented in the [docs](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Enumerable&method=.reduce&src=false).

Comment: Yeah, `Ember.Enumerable` offers some very nice methods for those kind of common tasks.